# Popular JavaScript Inheritance Patterns

Tags: javascript, inheritance, design-patterns

I'm working on an [ebook on GitHub](http://github.com/roblevintennis/Testing-and-Debugging-JavaScript/) on TDD JavaScript and I'm wondering if I'm missing any popular inheritance patterns. If you know of any additional patterns I'd love to see them. They should have the following:

1. Time tested - used in real apps
2. Source code should be supplied. Should be as straight forward and pedantic as possible.
3. Of course be correct and working.

The reason I'm doing this is that it seems that object inheritance in JavaScript has been quite difficult for many of us to grok. my JavaScript inheritance chapter is basically a study aid to: Crockford's Good Parts and Zakas's Professional JavaScript for Web Developers.

Here are the patterns I have so far:

```
// Pseudoclassical Inheritance
    function Animal(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.arr = [1,2,3];
    };
    Animal.prototype = {
        constructor: Animal,
        whoAmI: function() { return "I am " + this.name + "!\n"; }
    };

    function Dog(name, breed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
    };
    Dog.prototype = new Animal();
    Dog.prototype.getBreed = function() {
        return this.breed;
    };
    Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
        return 'ruff ruff';
    };

    // Combination Inheritance
    function Parent(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.arr = [1,2,3];
    };
    Parent.prototype = {
        constructor: Parent,
        toString: function() { return "My name is " + this.name; }
    };
    function Child(name, age) {
        Parent.call(this, name);
        this.age = age;
    };

    Child.prototype = new Parent();

    Child.prototype.getAge = function() {
        return this.age;
    };

    // Prototypal Inheritance
    var helper = { // Thanks to Bob Vince for reminding me NOT to clobber Object!

        inherit: function(p) {
        NewObj = function(){};
        NewObj.prototype = p;
        return new NewObj(); 
        },
        inheritPrototype: function(subType, superType) {
        var prototype = helper.inherit(superType.prototype);
        prototype.constructor = subType;
        subType.prototype = prototype;
        }
    };

    function SubType(name, age) {
        Parent.call(this, name);
        this.age = age;    
    };
    //Child.prototype = new Parent();   // Gets replaced by:
    helper.inheritPrototype(SubType, Parent);  
    SubType.prototype.getAge = function() {
        return this.age;
    };

    // Functional - Durable Pattern
    function super_func(blueprint) { 
        var obj = {};
        obj.getName = function() { return blueprint.name; };
        obj.getAge  = function() { return blueprint.age; };
        obj.getFoo  = function() { return blueprint.foo; };
        obj.getBar  = function() { return blueprint.bar; };
        return obj;
    };
    function sub_func(blueprint) {
        blueprint.name = blueprint.name || "Crockford's Place";
        supr = super_func(blueprint);
        supr.coolAugment = function() { return "I give a fresh new perspective on things!" };
        return supr;    
    };
```

And for those interested, here are the jspec tests (sorry but Markdown or whatever they're using mangles the format a bit):

```
describe 'JavaScript Inheritance Tests'
    before_each
    animal = new Animal("Onyx")
    dog = new Dog("Sebastian", "Lab")

    person = { password : 'secret', toString : function(){ return '<Person>' } }
    stub(person, 'toString').and_return('Original toString method!')    
    end
    describe 'Pseudoclassical Inheritance Creation'
    it 'should create parent and child object using pseudoclassical inheritance'
        animal.constructor.should.eql Animal
        // dog.constructor.should.eql Dog // Nope: expected Animal to eql Dog
        dog.constructor.should.eql Animal 
        animal.should.be_a Animal 
        dog.should.be_a Animal
        // dog.should.be_a Dog // Nope! We severed the original prototype pointer and now point to Animal!
        dog.should.be_an_instance_of Animal
        dog.should.be_an_instance_of Dog 
        (animal instanceof Dog).should.be_false
    end
    it 'should behave such that child inherits methods and instance variables defined in parent'
        animal.whoAmI().should.match /I am Onyx.*/ 
        dog.whoAmI().should.match /Sebastian.*/
        animal.should.respond_to 'whoAmI'
        dog.should.respond_to 'whoAmI'
        dog.should.have_prop 'name'
    end
    it 'should behave such that methods and instance variables added to child are NOT available to parent'
        dog.bark().should.match /Ruff Ruff/i
        dog.should.have_property 'breed'
        dog.should.respond_to 'bark'
        // animal.should.have_prop 'breed' // Of course not!
        // animal.should.respond_to 'bark' // Of course not!
    end
    it 'should behave such that reference variables on the parent are "staticy" to all child instances'
        dog.arr.should.eql([1,2,3]) 
        dog.arr.push(4)
        dog.arr.should.eql([1,2,3,4]) 
        spike = new Dog("Spike", "Pitbull")
        spike.arr.should.eql([1,2,3,4]) 
        spike.arr.push(5)
        rover = new Dog("Rover", "German Sheppard")
        spike.arr.should.eql([1,2,3,4,5])
        rover.arr.should.eql([1,2,3,4,5])
        dog.arr.should.eql([1,2,3,4,5])
    end 
    end

    describe 'Combination Inheritance Solves Static Prototype Properties Issue'
    it 'should maintain separate state for each child object'
        child_1 = new Child("David", 21)
        child_2 = new Child("Peter", 32)
        child_1.arr.push(999)
        child_2.arr.push(333)
        child_1.arr.should.eql([1,2,3,999])
        child_2.arr.should.eql([1,2,3,333])
        child_1.getAge().should.eql 21
        child_1.should.be_a Parent
    end
    end

    describe 'Prototypal Inheritance'
    it 'should inherit properties from parent'
        person.toString().should.match /Original toString.*/i
        person.password.should.eql 'secret'
        joe = helper.inherit(person)
        joe.password.should.eql 'secret'
        joe.password = 'letmein'
        joe.password.should.eql 'letmein'
        person.password.should.eql 'secret'
    end
    end

    describe 'Parisitic Combination Inheritance'
    it 'should use inheritPrototype (to call parent constructor once) and still work as expected'
        sub = new SubType("Nicholas Zakas", 29)
        sub.toString().should.match /.*Nicholas Zakas/
        sub.getAge().should.eql 29
        charlie = new SubType("Charlie Brown", 69)
        charlie.arr.should.eql([1,2,3])
        charlie.arr.push(999)
        charlie.arr.should.eql([1,2,3,999])
        sub.arr.should.eql([1,2,3]) 
        sub.should.be_an_instance_of SubType
        charlie.should.be_an_instance_of SubType
        (sub instanceof SubType).should.eql true 
        (sub instanceof Parent).should.eql true 
    end
    end

    describe 'Functional Durable Inheritance'
    it 'should hide private variables'
        sup = new super_func( {name: "Superfly Douglas", age: 39, foo: "foo", bar: "bar"} )
        sup.getName().should.eql 'Superfly Douglas'
        sup.name.should.be_undefined
        sup.getAge().should.eql 39 
        sup.age.should.be_undefined
        sup.getFoo().should.eql 'foo'
        sup.foo.should.be_undefined
    end

    it 'should create a descendent object that inherits properties while maintaining privacy'
        sub = new sub_func( {name: "Submarine", age: 1, foo: "food", bar: "barfly"} )
        sub.getName().should.eql 'Submarine'
        sub.name.should.be_undefined
        sub.getAge().should.eql 1 
        sub.age.should.be_undefined
        sub.getFoo().should.eql 'food'
        sub.foo.should.be_undefined 
        sub.getBar().should.eql 'barfly'
        sub.bar.should.be_undefined 
        sub.coolAugment().should.match /.*fresh new perspective.*/
        //sub.should.be_an_instance_of super_func NOPE!
        //sub.should.be_an_instance_of sub_func   NOPE!
        sub.should.be_an_instance_of Object 
    end
    end

end
```

Thanks all! Oh, and if you want to check out my essay/book I'd love to get feedback:
[TDD JavaScript at GitHub repo](http://github.com/roblevintennis/Testing-and-Debugging-JavaScript/)

Comment: I tried a lot of techniques on a lot of different projects. My favorite is using Object.create() to instantiate the base prototype. Check my blog: http://ncombo.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/javascript-inheritance-done-right/

Answer (score 8):

See [How to "properly" create a custom object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript#1598077) for a summary. (Might as well link it, since I wasted so much time typing it out!)

this:

> Dog.prototype = new Animal();

would generally be avoided. You see it in example/tutorial code, but it's a horrible mess because it's basing a class on an instance, and an instance constructed in a faulty way: `name` is undefined. Any more complicated constructor is going to get upset at that sort of thing.

> Object.prototype.inherit=

Is a better approach for constructing, but prototyping anything into `Object` is considered very poor taste. It runs the risk of messing up use of objects as trivial maps and breaking other code. You can put this helper function elsewhere, eg. `Function.prototype.subclass`.

> prototype.constructor

Personally I would tend to avoid, because `constructor` has a special meaning in JavaScript (as implemented in Firefox and some other browsers; not IE's JScript), and that meaning is not what `constructor` does here nor what you would expect any such property to do; it's confusing and almost always best avoided. So if including a link to the constructor function in the instance in a class system I would prefer to name it something else.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I agree about Object.prototype.inherit and I think I mention this in my essay but I'll at least add it to the comments on the code and/or put it in a wrapper function. Thanks for catching that! Dog.prototype = new Animal() I give alternatives in later patterns. Thanks for your input Bob.

Comment: I went ahead and updated the code (and edited the above code listing) to use a helper object as opposed to clobbering Object.

Comment: Yup, I went back and read my essay and I say: 'There's of course nothing requiring you to monkey patch Object – you could create a wrapper that returns such functionality if you wish.' Just plain lazy!!! Thanks for making me "do it right"!

Answer (score 1):

A co-worker at my previous company developed a library to do java like inheritance http://www.uselesspickles.com/class_library/. I think it's sexier than Rajendra's suggestions, syntax looks cleaner.

I wrote an article that demonstrates different ways to approach it, but making sure that the known bad practices are avoided. http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html, this is if you don't want to download a library but just want to copy paste some code that you can improve to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

There's an interesting pattern worth mentioning here: a JavaScript constructor may return any object (not necesserily *this*). One could create a constructor function, that returns a proxy object, that contains proxy methods to the "real" methods of the "real" instance object. This may sound complicated, but it is not; here is a code snippet:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    var instanceObj = this;
    var proxyObj = {
        myPublicMethod: function() {
            return instanceObj.myPublicMethod.apply(instanceObj, arguments);
        }
    }
    return proxyObj;
};
MyClass.prototype = {
    _myPrivateMethod: function() {
        ...
    },
    myPublicMethod: function() {
        ...
    }
};
```

The nice thing is that the proxy creation can be automated, if we define a convention for naming the protected methods. I created a little library that does exactly this: http://idya.github.com/oolib/

Answer (score 0):

I've got at least half a dozen implementations of various inheritance patterns lying around in my `dev/web/stuff` folder, but they are mostly toys.

What I actually sometimes use is the following thin wrapper over JavaScript's default pseudo-class-based approach to make inheritance easier:

```
Function.prototype.derive = (function() {
    function Dummy() {}
    return function() {
        Dummy.prototype = this.prototype;
        return new Dummy;
    };
})();
```

Example code:

```
function Pet(owner, type, name) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
}

Pet.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.owner + '\'s ' + this.type + ' ' + this.name;
};

function Cat(owner, name) {
    Pet.call(this, owner, 'cat', name);
}

Cat.prototype = Pet.derive();

var souris = new Cat('Christoph', 'Souris');
```

Another interesting one is the following, which automatically adds factory methods to a proper prototypal approach:

```
var Proto = new (function() {
    function Dummy() {}

    this.clone = function() {
        Dummy.prototype = this;
        return new Dummy;
    };

    this.init = function() {};

    this.create = function() {
        var obj = this.clone();
        this.init.apply(obj, arguments);
        return obj;
    };
});
```

Example code:

```
var Pet = Proto.clone();

Pet.init = function(owner, type, name) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
};

Pet.toString = function() {
    return this.owner + '\'s ' + this.type + ' ' + this.name;
};

Cat = Pet.clone();

Cat.init = function(owner, name) {
    Pet.init.call(this, owner, 'cat', name);
};

// use factory method
var filou = Cat.create('Christoph', 'Filou');

// use cloning (the proper prototypal approach)
var red = filou.clone();
red.name = 'Red';
```

You've [already seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404559/what-will-be-a-good-minimalistic-javascript-inheritance-method/1404697#1404697) my [implementation of classes](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/class.js).

Comment: Hi Christoph! Thanks. So your derive method is really the same as my inherit method except it returns a closure and calls 'itself'; the pattern also uses constructor stealing - I think it's essentially a combination inheritance pattern (prototypal and constructor stealing combined). I'm going to need to stare at the other pattern a bit longer - I think I'll play with it tonight and report back ;-) Thanks for sharing Christoph.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here but I have 2 points to make.

1) Please do not inform people to inherit through creating supertype objects. This is considered bad practice for a few reason. Firstly, its a principle mistake. You are instantiating objects just to use their methods and not doing anything with the instance per se. The right way to have done this is to use the Object.prototype.inherit method. In addition, this method forces you to leave the supertype constructor function argument empty, which may invoke an error under strict circumstances.

2) You forgot to mention the constructor stealing pattern.

```
function Supertype(name){
 this.name=name;
 this.sayName = function(){console.log(this.name);};
} 

function Subtype(name){
 //inherit by using (stealing) supertype constructor function
 Supertype(name);

 // child specific properties
 //
}
```