# How to inherit from a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

In PHP/Java one can do:

```
class Sub extends Base
{
}
```

And automatically all public/protected methods, properties, fields, etc of the Super class become a part of the Sub class which can be overridden if necessary.

What's the equivalent for that in Javascript?

Comment: link :
http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html , or

http://phrogz.net/JS/Classes/OOPinJS2.html

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908443/what-are-good-javascript-oop-resources

Comment: Does that crockford way still work? ZParenizor.inherits(Parenizor);

Comment: See also: [JavaScript Extending Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192722/javascript-extending-class/15192747#15192747)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I have changed how I do this now, I try to avoid using constructor functions and their `prototype` property, but my old answer from 2010 is still at the bottom. I now prefer `Object.create()`.  `Object.create` is available in all modern browsers.

I should note that `Object.create` is usually [much slower](http://jsperf.com/object-create-vs-crockford-vs-jorge-vs-constructor/26) than using `new` with a function constructor.

```
//The prototype is just an object when you use `Object.create()`
var Base = {};

//This is how you create an instance:
var baseInstance = Object.create(Base);

//If you want to inherit from "Base":
var subInstance = Object.create(Object.create(Base));

//Detect if subInstance is an instance of Base:
console.log(Base.isPrototypeOf(subInstance)); //True
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btipling/2e79g3c4/)

One of the big benefits of using Object.create is being able to pass in a [defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) argument, which gives you significant control over how properties on the class can be accessed and enumerated over, and I also use functions to create instances, these serve as constructors in a way, as you can do initialization at the end instead of just returning the instance.

```
var Base = {};

function createBase() {
  return Object.create(Base, {
    doSomething: {
       value: function () {
         console.log("Doing something");
       },
    },
  });
}

var Sub = createBase();

function createSub() {
  return Object.create(Sub, {
    doSomethingElse: {
      value: function () {
        console.log("Doing something else");
      },
    },
  }); 
}

var subInstance = createSub();
subInstance.doSomething(); //Logs "Doing something"
subInstance.doSomethingElse(); //Logs "Doing something else"
console.log(Base.isPrototypeOf(subInstance)); //Logs "true"
console.log(Sub.isPrototypeOf(subInstance)); //Logs "true
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btipling/a034tg7c/)

This is my original answer from 2010:

```
function Base ( ) {
  this.color = "blue";
}

function Sub ( ) {

}
Sub.prototype = new Base( );
Sub.prototype.showColor = function ( ) {
 console.log( this.color );
}

var instance = new Sub ( );
instance.showColor( ); //"blue"
```

Comment: How about sub.prototype.constructor value? I think it should be set too to sub value.

Comment: Besides you are using reserved keywords ('super') as classnames, I wasn't able to get your example running: http://jsbin.com/ixiyet/8/edit

Comment: @MOnsDaR I renamed it to Base

Comment: If I use `alert()` to see what `instance.showColor()` returns I still get `undefined`. http://jsbin.com/uqalin/1/

Comment: @MOnsDaR that's because it console logs, it doesn't return anything for alert to show. Do you see a return statement in showColor?

Comment: I used `alert` in my copy of your code, see the annotated jsbin-link. I'm not here to mess around, just wanted to give you notice that I had problems by using your code.

Comment: I just copied and pasted exactly as it is there in Chrome and it worked. It worked with alert too. Thanks for pointing out the super issue.

Comment: Thank you for updating you answer. This serves as an excellent best-practice for prototypal inheritance, as `Object.create()` is now [ubiquitous](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.create).

Answer (score 195):

In JavaScript you don't have *classes* but you can get inheritance and behavior reuse in many ways:

**Pseudo-classical inheritance (through prototyping):**

```
function Super () {
  this.member1 = 'superMember1';
}
Super.prototype.member2 = 'superMember2';

function Sub() {
  this.member3 = 'subMember3';
  //...
}
Sub.prototype = new Super();
```

Should be used with the `new` operator:

```
var subInstance = new Sub();
```

**Function application or "constructor chaining":**

```
function Super () {
  this.member1 = 'superMember1';
  this.member2 = 'superMember2';
}


function Sub() {
  Super.apply(this, arguments);
  this.member3 = 'subMember3';
}
```

This approach should also be used with the `new` operator:

```
var subInstance = new Sub();
```

The difference with the first example is that when we `apply` the `Super` constructor to the `this` object inside `Sub`, it adds the properties assigned to `this` on `Super`, directly on the new instance, e.g. `subInstance` contains the properties `member1` and `member2` directly (`subInstance.hasOwnProperty('member1') == true;`).

In the first example, those properties are reached through the *prototype chain*, they exist on an internal `[[Prototype]]` object.

**Parasitic inheritance or Power Constructors:**

```
function createSuper() {
  var obj = {
    member1: 'superMember1',
    member2: 'superMember2'
  };

  return obj;
}

function createSub() {
  var obj = createSuper();
  obj.member3 = 'subMember3';
  return obj;
}
```

This approach is based basically on "object augmenting", you don't need to use the `new` operator, and as you can see, the `this` keyword is not involved.

```
var subInstance = createSub();
```

**ECMAScript 5th Ed. `Object.create` method:**

```
// Check if native implementation available
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
  Object.create = function (o) {
    function F() {}  // empty constructor
    F.prototype = o; // set base object as prototype
    return new F();  // return empty object with right [[Prototype]]
  };
}

var superInstance = {
  member1: 'superMember1',
  member2: 'superMember2'
};

var subInstance = Object.create(superInstance);
subInstance.member3 = 'subMember3';
```

The above method is a prototypal inheritance technique proposed by [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html).

Object instances inherit from other object instances, that's it.

This technique can be better than simple "object augmentation" because the inherited properties aren't copied over all the new object instances, since the *base* object is set as the `[[Prototype]]` of the *extended* object, in the above example `subInstance` contains physically only the `member3` property.

Comment: don't use instances for inheritance - use ES5 `Object.create()` or a custom `clone()` function (eg  http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/js-hacks/raw-file/tip/clone.js ) to inherit directly from the prototype object; see the comments to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404559/what-will-be-a-good-minimalistic-javascript-inheritance-method/1404697#1404697 for an explanation

Comment: Thanks @Christoph, I was about to mention the `Object.create` method :)

Comment: This is not proper inheritance, since you will have Super's instance members on  Sub's prototype.
Hence all of the Sub's instances will share the same `member1` variable, which is not desirable at all. Of course they can rewrite it, but that just doesn't make sense.

https://github.com/dotnetwise/Javascript-FastClass is a better sugar solution.

Comment: Hello @CMS, could you explain please, why do I need to create instance of the parent class in the first example to setup inheritance for the sub-class? I'm talking about this line: `Sub.prototype = new Super();`. What if both classes are never going to be used during script execution? It looks like performance issue. Why do I need to create parent class if child class is not actually used? Can you elaborate please? Here's the simple demonstration of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/slavafomin/ZeVL2/ Thanks!

Comment: In all the examples -- except the last one -- there are is a "class" for Super and a "class" for Sub, and then you create an instance of the Sub. Can you add a comparable example for the Object.create example?

Answer (score 56):

## For those who reach this page in 2019 or after

With the latest version of the ECMAScript standard **(ES6)**, you can use the keyword `class`.

Note that the class definition is not a regular `object`; hence there are no commas between class members.
To create an instance of a class, you must use the `new` keyword. To inherit from a base class, use `extends`:

```
class Vehicle {
   constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.kind = 'vehicle';
   }
   getName() {
      return this.name;
   }   
}

// Create an instance
var myVehicle = new Vehicle('rocky');
myVehicle.getName(); // => 'rocky'
```

To inherit from a base class, use `extends`:

```
class Car extends Vehicle {
   constructor(name) {
      super(name);
      this.kind = 'car'
   }
}

var myCar = new Car('bumpy');

myCar.getName(); // => 'bumpy'
myCar instanceof Car; // => true
myCar instanceof Vehicle; // => true
```

From the derived class, you can use super from any constructor or method to access its base class:

- To call the parent constructor, use `super().`
- To call another member,    use, for example, `super.getName()`.

There’s more to using classes. If you want to dig deeper into the subject, I recommend “[Classes in ECMAScript 6](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html)” by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer.*

[source](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/10/es6-whats-new-next-version-javascript/)

Comment: Under the hood, `class` and `extends` is (ultra useful) syntax sugar for the prototype chain: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23877420/895245

Comment: just for your information 'instance.name' here 'mycar.name' will return the name of the class. This is a default behaviour of ES6 and ESnext. Here for mycar.name will return 'Vehicle'

Answer (score 8):

I find this quote to be the most enlightening:

> In essence, a JavaScript ***"class"*** is just a Function object that serves as a constructor plus an attached prototype object. ([Source: Guru Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/))

I like using constructors rather than objects, so I'm partial to the "pseudo-classical inheritance" method [described here by CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2107586/1766230). Here is an example of **multiple inheritance with a prototype chain**:

```
// Lifeform "Class" (Constructor function, No prototype)
function Lifeform () {
    this.isLifeform = true;
}

// Animal "Class" (Constructor function + prototype for inheritance)
function Animal () {
    this.isAnimal = true;
}
Animal.prototype = new Lifeform();

// Mammal "Class" (Constructor function + prototype for inheritance)
function Mammal () {
    this.isMammal = true;
}
Mammal.prototype = new Animal();

// Cat "Class" (Constructor function + prototype for inheritance)
function Cat (species) {
    this.isCat = true;
    this.species = species
}
Cat.prototype = new Mammal();

// Make an instance object of the Cat "Class"
var tiger = new Cat("tiger");

console.log(tiger);
// The console outputs a Cat object with all the properties from all "classes"

console.log(tiger.isCat, tiger.isMammal, tiger.isAnimal, tiger.isLifeform);
// Outputs: true true true true

// You can see that all of these "is" properties are available in this object
// We can check to see which properties are really part of the instance object
console.log( "tiger hasOwnProperty: "
    ,tiger.hasOwnProperty("isLifeform") // false
    ,tiger.hasOwnProperty("isAnimal")   // false
    ,tiger.hasOwnProperty("isMammal")   // false
    ,tiger.hasOwnProperty("isCat")      // true
);

// New properties can be added to the prototypes of any
// of the "classes" above and they will be usable by the instance
Lifeform.prototype.A    = 1;
Animal.prototype.B      = 2;
Mammal.prototype.C      = 3;
Cat.prototype.D         = 4;

console.log(tiger.A, tiger.B, tiger.C, tiger.D);
// Console outputs: 1 2 3 4

// Look at the instance object again
console.log(tiger);
// You'll see it now has the "D" property
// The others are accessible but not visible (console issue?)
// In the Chrome console you should be able to drill down the __proto__ chain
// You can also look down the proto chain with Object.getPrototypeOf
// (Equivalent to tiger.__proto__)
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(tiger) );  // Mammal 
console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(tiger)) ); // Animal
// Etc. to get to Lifeform
```

Here is [another good resource from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), and here is [a jsfiddle so you can try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/luken/q4vtcvg3/).

Answer (score 7):

Well, in JavaScript there is no "class inheritance", there is just "prototype inheritance". So you don't make a class "truck" and then mark it as a subclass of "automobile". Instead, you make an object "Jack" and say that it uses "John" as a prototype. If John knows, how much "4+4" is, then Jack knows it, too.

I suggest you read Douglas Crockford's article about prototypal inheritance here: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html He also shows how you can make JavaScript have "look-alike" inheritance as in other OO languages and then explains that this actually means breaking javaScript in a way it was not meant to be used.

Comment: Let's assume Jack's prototype is John. During run-time I added a property/behavior to John. Will I get that property/behavior from Jack?

Comment: You sure will. For instance, this is how people typically add "trim()" method to all string objects (it is not built-in) See an example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 5):

Javascript inheritance is a bit different from Java and PHP, because it doesn't really have classes. Instead it has prototype objects that provide methods and member variables. You can chain those prototypes to provide object inheritance. The most common pattern I found when researching this question is described on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Example.3A_Classical_inheritance_with_Object.create()). I've updated their example to include a call to a superclass method and to show the log in an alert message:

```js
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  log += 'Shape moved.\n';
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

// Override method
Rectangle.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  Shape.prototype.move.call(this, x, y); // call superclass method
  log += 'Rectangle moved.\n';
}

var log = "";
var rect = new Rectangle();

log += ('Is rect an instance of Rectangle? ' + (rect instanceof Rectangle) + '\n'); // true
log += ('Is rect an instance of Shape? ' + (rect instanceof Shape) + '\n'); // true
rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
alert(log);
```

Personally, I find inheritance in Javascript awkward, but this is the best version I've found.

Answer (score 3):

you can't (in the classical sense).  Javascript is a prototypical language.  You will observe that you never declare a "class" in Javascript; you merely define the state and methods of an object.  To produce inheritance, you take some object and prototype it.  The prototype is extended with new functionality.

Answer (score 2):

### ES6 classes:

Javascript does not have classes. Classes in javascript are is just syntactical sugar build on top of the **prototypal inheritance** pattern that javascript. You can use the JS `class` to enforce prototypal inheritance but it is important to realize that you are actually still using constructor functions under the hood.

These concepts also apply when you are extending from a `es6` 'class' using the extends keyword. This just creates an additional link in the prototype chain. The `__proto__`

### Example:

```js
class Animal {
  makeSound () {
    console.log('animalSound');
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
   makeSound () {
    console.log('Woof');
  }
}


console.log(typeof Dog)  // classes in JS are just constructor functions under the hood

const dog = new Dog();

console.log(dog.__proto__ === Dog.prototype);   
// First link in the prototype chain is Dog.prototype

console.log(dog.__proto__.__proto__ === Animal.prototype);  
// Second link in the prototype chain is Animal.prototype
// The extends keyword places Animal in the prototype chain
// Now Dog 'inherits' the makeSound property from Animal
```

### Object.create()

`Object.create()` is also a way to create inheritance in JS in javascript. `Object.create()` is a function which creates a new object, an takes an existing object as an argument. It will assign the object which was received as an argument to the `__proto__` property of the newly created object. Again it is important to realize we are bound to the prototypal inheritance paradigm which JS embodies.

### Example:

```js
const Dog = {
  fluffy: true,
  bark: () => {
      console.log('woof im a relatively cute dog or something else??');
  }
};

const dog = Object.create(Dog);

dog.bark();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.inheritWith` and `.fastClass` [library](https://github.com/dotnetwise/Javascript-FastClass). It is faster than most popular libraries and sometimes even faster than the native version.

Very easy to use:

```
function Super() {
   this.member1 = "superMember";//instance member
}.define({ //define methods on Super's prototype
   method1: function() { console.log('super'); } //prototype member
}.defineStatic({ //define static methods directly on Super function 
   staticMethod1: function() { console.log('static method on Super'); }
});

var Sub = Super.inheritWith(function(base, baseCtor) {
   return {
      constructor: function() {//the Sub constructor that will be returned to variable Sub
         this.member3 = 'subMember3'; //instance member on Sub
         baseCtor.apply(this, arguments);//call base construcor and passing all incoming arguments
      },
      method1: function() { 
         console.log('sub'); 
         base.method1.apply(this, arguments); //call the base class' method1 function
      }
}
```

Usage

```
var s = new Sub();
s.method1(); //prints:
//sub 
//super
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Person(attr){
  this.name = (attr && attr.name)? attr.name : undefined;
  this.birthYear = (attr && attr.birthYear)? attr.birthYear : undefined;

  this.printName = function(){
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  this.printBirthYear = function(){
    console.log(this.birthYear);
  }
  this.print = function(){
    console.log(this.name + '(' +this.birthYear+ ')');
  }
}

function PersonExt(attr){
  Person.call(this, attr);

  this.print = function(){
    console.log(this.name+ '-' + this.birthYear);
  }
  this.newPrint = function(){
    console.log('New method');
  }
}
PersonExt.prototype = new Person();

// Init object and call methods
var p = new Person({name: 'Mr. A', birthYear: 2007});
// Parent method
p.print() // Mr. A(2007)
p.printName() // Mr. A

var pExt = new PersonExt({name: 'Mr. A', birthYear: 2007});
// Overwriten method
pExt.print() // Mr. A-2007
// Extended method
pExt.newPrint() // New method
// Parent method
pExt.printName() // Mr. A
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading many posts, i came up with this solution ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chauwel/y6wf0y3t/10/)). Most of the time i don't need something more sophisticated

```
var Class = function(definition) {
    var base = definition.extend || null;
    var construct = definition.construct || definition.extend || function() {};

    var newClass = function() { 
        this._base_ = base;        
        construct.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    if (definition.name) 
        newClass._name_ = definition.name;

    if (definition.extend) {
        var f = function() {}       
        f.prototype = definition.extend.prototype;      
        newClass.prototype = new f();   
        newClass.prototype.constructor = newClass;
        newClass._extend_ = definition.extend;      
        newClass._base_ = definition.extend.prototype;         
    }

    if (definition.statics) 
        for (var n in definition.statics) newClass[n] = definition.statics[n];          

    if (definition.members) 
        for (var n in definition.members) newClass.prototype[n] = definition.members[n];    

    return newClass;
}


var Animal = Class({

    construct: function() {        
    },

    members: {

        speak: function() {
            console.log("nuf said");                        
        },

        isA: function() {        
            return "animal";           
        }        
    }
});


var Dog = Class({  extend: Animal,

    construct: function(name) {  
        this._base_();        
        this.name = name;
    },

    statics: {
        Home: "House",
        Food: "Meat",
        Speak: "Barks"
    },

    members: {
        name: "",

        speak: function() {
            console.log( "ouaf !");         
        },

        isA: function(advice) {
           return advice + " dog -> " + Dog._base_.isA.call(this);           
        }        
    }
});


var Yorkshire = Class({ extend: Dog,

    construct: function(name,gender) {
        this._base_(name);      
        this.gender = gender;
    },

    members: {
        speak: function() {
            console.log( "ouin !");           
        },

        isA: function(advice) {         
           return "yorkshire -> " + Yorkshire._base_.isA.call(this,advice);       
        }        
    }
});


var Bulldog = function() { return _class_ = Class({ extend: Dog,

    construct: function(name) {
        this._base_(name);      
    },

    members: {
        speak: function() {
            console.log( "OUAF !");           
        },

        isA: function(advice) {         
           return "bulldog -> " + _class_._base_.isA.call(this,advice);       
        }        
    }
})}();


var animal = new Animal("Maciste");
console.log(animal.isA());
animal.speak();

var dog = new Dog("Sultan");
console.log(dog.isA("good"));
dog.speak();

var yorkshire = new Yorkshire("Golgoth","Male");
console.log(yorkshire.isA("bad"));
yorkshire.speak();

var bulldog = new Bulldog("Mike");
console.log(bulldog.isA("nice"));
bulldog.speak();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to CMS's answer and after fiddling for a while with prototype and Object.create and what not, I was able to come up with a neat solution for my inheritance using apply as shown here:

```
var myNamespace = myNamespace || (function() {
    return {

        BaseClass: function(){
            this.someBaseProperty = "someBaseProperty";
            this.someProperty = "BaseClass";
            this.someFunc = null;
        },

        DerivedClass:function(someFunc){
            myNamespace.BaseClass.apply(this, arguments);
            this.someFunc = someFunc;
            this.someProperty = "DerivedClass";
        },

        MoreDerivedClass:function(someFunc){
            myNamespace.DerivedClass.apply(this, arguments);
            this.someFunc = someFunc;
            this.someProperty = "MoreDerivedClass";
        }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

From ES2015, that's exactly how you do inheritance in JavaScript

```
class Sub extends Base {

}
```

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
2. http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html

Answer (score 1):

```
function Base() {
    this.doSomething = function () {
    }
}

function Sub() {
    Base.call(this); // inherit Base's method(s) to this instance of Sub
}

var sub = new Sub();
sub.doSomething();
```

Comment: Please don't just post code, explain what it does and how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inherit from a class in JavaScript, because there are no classes in JavaScript.