# Maintaining a unique array of functions

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I assumed that functions could passed around like normal values in Javascript. I thought that they evaluated to some address. From the output of the following example, I seem to be right.

```
var f = function() { console.info('f'); };
var v = function() { console.info('v'); };

var arr = [];

arr.push(f);
arr.push(f);
arr;            // [function(), function()]
arr.uniq();     // [function()]
arr.push(f);
arr.push(f);
arr.push(v);
arr;            // [function(), function(), function()]
arr.without(f); // [function()]
arr.first()();  // v
```

However, once I applied this observation to "object oriented" code, `uniq` and `without` stopped working.

```
A = Class.create({
 initialize: function() {
 },
 callback: function() {
 },
 add: function() {
  b.add(this.callback.bind(this));
 }
 remove: function() {
  b.remove(this.callback.bind(this));
 }
});

a = new A();

B = Class.create({
 initialize: function() {
  this.funcs = [];
 },
 add: function(func) {
  this.funcs.push(func);
  this.funcs = this.funcs.uniq();
 },
 remove: function(func) {
  this.funcs = this.funcs.without(func);
 }
});

b = new B();

a.add();  // b.funcs = [function()]
a.add();  // b.funcs = [function(), function()]
a.remove; // b.funcs = [function(), function()]
```

Every time you call `b.add`, `a.funcs` grows larger; `uniq` does not strip the duplicates. And every time you call `b.remove`, `a.funcs` does not shrink; `without` has failed to find the function.

It appears to me that I'm appending functions that resolve to different address every time. Does `bind` give a new address each time? How do I fix this? I want to ensure that there's never two of the same function in `a`'s `this.funcs`; It's okay if two functions defined in two different places do the same thing, but not okay if the same function handle were in the array twice.

Comment: From the prototypejs docs for `bind`: *"Binds this function to the given context by wrapping it in another function and returning the wrapper."* So I'd say that yes, you're getting new functions. EDIT: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/zDpkQ/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea - that JS functions are first-class citizens, and that `bind` returns a new function each time it's called. However, what you *want* to do is impossible. It is computationally impossible to determine if two different functions do the same thing for all inputs.

There's a similar question I saw a little while ago, <s>let me see if I can dig it up.</s> [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844043/are-two-functions-equal).

Comment: I only want to have uniquely defined functions in the array. I don't mind if two different functions that do the same thing are both in the array.

Comment: @JoJo: that's all well and good, but how do you define "uniquely defined functions?" (cf. my edit) You could use a hash to enforce "uniqueness" instead of an array, if you have some reasonable way to generate strings that could be used as the hash keys.

Comment: Consider the two functions: `foo = function(){alert(1);}` and `bar = function(){alert(1);}`. These are two functions that do the same thing but are uniquely defined. They would be allowed to coexist in my array. But two or more `foo`s would not be allowed to coexist in my array.

Comment: I could just store the functions as their string representation as someFunction.toString(). This would allow me to use `uniq` and `without` to maintain both functionally unique and uniquely defined functions. But I only wanted to enforce the latter.

Comment: @JoJo: so, you're okay with your array containing both `foo` and `bar` as your comment describes? I still don't really understand what you mean by "uniquely defined functions." Do you mean "distinct function instances?"

Comment: I guess that's what mean. A *uniquely defined function* should strictly equate to itself in the absence of `bind`.

Comment: @JoJo: then in that case, you need to avoid `bind()`, since it returns new functions.

Comment: If I don't `bind`, then I cannot use `this` in the callback function. I would have to literally refer to the object as `a`. Isn't this considered poor coding style? If it's the only way, then I guess I'm forced to write ugly code.

Comment: @JoJo: no, actually, if you're careful about how you invoke the callback. When invoking the callback, you can use `callback.apply(/* whatever "this" should be here*/)`. [`Function#apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply)

Comment: @JoJo: ...that said, I don't see why you're creating mutually-dependent "classes." It sounds like you're trying to impose class-based inheritance on top of JS' prototype-based inheritance, which is just a bad idea. I recommend reading [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129789/class-inheritance-in-javascript/2129800#2129800) if you haven't already. But really, you're not even using the `prototype` (not the be confused with the JS library you _are_ using) - all that to say, I don't really see what you're trying to accomplish with these mutually-dependent objects.

Comment: Here's the full story. I'm making a video player (`B`). I have a class that handles the internals of this video player. I have an encompassing application that uses the video player among other things.  I also have a class for such an app (`A`). The app would like to register a callback that the video player should call once all videos in the playlist are played. The video player should have a safety net, preventing multiple instances of the callback from being enqueued.