# javascript inheritance - from abstract idea to actual code

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

i know how to inherit in c++, vb(6-shame on me), and php

I saw many examples and tutorials about it regarding javascript. but no simple explanation about it.
What i need is an starting point that will leave me with the need to learn "just" the syntax and usage.

hope i am clear enough.
thanks

Comment: Well, what have you read and what didn't you understand? You will probably get links to sources you already read...

Comment: There are many ways to implement inheritance in JavaScript, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107556/how-to-inherit-from-a-class-in-javascript/2107586#2107586), I give a small overview of the most popular techniques.

Comment: thank you felix, you are correct, i've read enough :) the crockford's text was very helpful,still have to read some more -but i am okay now.

thanks CMS, checking it out now,seems promising :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crockford is the king - so I highly recommend reading the link provided by @hvgotcodes

Since you asked for practical implementation, I wrote up an example a while back showcasing the practical application of the OO paradigm in JS -

http://tikkunology.blogspot.com/2010/02/practical-object-oriented-javascript.html

Hopefully it'll help

Answer (score 3):

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

check that out.  Note prototypal inheritance is nothing like classical inheritance.