# javascript function object's inherit method behaviour

Tags: javascript, oop, function, inheritance, object

I've come across a behaviour of the function object. that seems to be similar to prototyping but uses a different method.

```
var Car = function() {
    this.foo = 'shiny';
}

var Rover = function() {
    this.inherit = Car;
    this.inherit();
}

var Mini = function() {
    this.inherit = Car;
    this.inherit();
}
```

when a new instance of a sub class is made this.inherit method has the effect of calling the parent class on itself, so that the parent's properties and methods are available to the sub class.

```
var myRover = new Rover();

var myMini = new Mini();
myMini.foo = 'rusty';

console.log(myRover.foo, myMini.foo); // displays "shiny" & "rusty" respectively
```

I've looked in Mozilla and MSDN, but I can't seem to find it documented any where.  Can anyone put a name to this behaviour and any further documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word `inheritFrom` does not make any sense here. It could be as well `bar`. What makes this work is the pattern that you define a member of the "subClass" function which you call on the next line.

It may be worth checking out "[Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html)" article by Douglas Crockford for some additional ideas.

Answer (score 0):

`inheritFrom` isn't a method that exists in JavaScript core objects. JavaScript inheritance can be accomplished in many ways [as outlined in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107556/how-to-inherit-from-a-class-in-javascript/2107586#2107586). What you're doing here is not really proper inheritance as you're just setting a single method in a separate object equal to a function.

First you declare a function called `superClass`. This function sets the `foo` and `bar` properties of the `this` object. When you set a method on `subClass` equal to `superClass` the `this` object then references the `subClass` function because it is the method's caller so then subClass has the properties of `foo` and `bar` set to `'foo'` and `'bar'`.

However, when you overwrite the foo method here:

```
this.foo = function() {
    return this.foo;
};
```

You turn foo into a function.

Notice that when you add this script:

```
var test = new subClass();
alert(test.foo);
```

`test.foo` will be a function as you overrode its value in the `subClass` constructor. Adding this:

```
alert(test.bar);
```

Will alert the string `'bar'` since you didn't overwrite it. Also if you call `test.foo()` it will simply return a pointer to the `test.foo` method.

Comment: I've made an edit to the method name so it makes more sense. the subClass method returns the inherited property. the post looks interesting because it uses a third type of inheritance using a "apply" method

Comment: @gawpertron: Basically what I'm trying to tell you is that you're not really doing inheritance here. You're simply saying that there will be a method on the `subClass` object called `myFunction` (or whatever). This `myFunction` runs the script inside of your `superClass` function. The `this` keyword in the `superClass` function references its caller, which in this case will be the `subClass` method.

Comment: I've removed the function. I can see now that it makes no difference what you call the method "inheritFrom", "inherit" or "monkeys" it has the same effect as using the "new" keyword but instead appends the properties and methods to the sub class.

Comment: @gawpertron So what's your question? Your original question was why it wasn't documented. It isn't documented because it's not a core method of object. Maybe you should accept one of the answers and open a new question if you have further issues.