# Determine whether member is defined in (Javascript) super class

Tags: javascript

I am using "[constructor chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107556/how-to-inherit-from-a-class-in-javascript/2107586#2107586)" to define a base class (Super).

```
function Super () {
  this.member1 = 'superMember1';
  this.member2 = 'superMember2';
}

function Sub() {
  Super.call(this, arguments);
  this.member3 = 'subMember3';
  var t = this.hasOwnProperty("member1"); // gives me true, so I cannot use it
}
```

How can I test whether a member (1,2,3) is defined (belonging) in my Sub class or in the Super class?

Remark: `this["name"]' is not the way, because I can only decide whether a value has been assigned - not if it is belonging to Super or Sub.

As [Darhazer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248935/determine-whether-member-is-defined-in-javascript-super-class/7248965#7248965) comments below, constructor chaining copies the members, so it might be tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously as of the answers so far, not possible. Hence will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

use hasOwnProperty() to check if the member is defined in the current class. If not -obviously it's defined by superclass.

Comment: Unfortunately this is *not* working, because this.hasOwnProperty("member1"); gives me true in Sub. Did anybody test this, because I appreciate the answer, but it is not working and already got 2 votes. So I either do something wrong, or the answer is not applicable to my scenario.

Comment: @Horst Walter Well it seems it's well documented in the constructor chaining topic, the properties are copied and hasOwnProperty returns true; this works only for prototype-based inheritance :(

Comment: Yep, I agree with this, this is why I am asking whether there is some way to find this out - but I could explicitly outline this already in the question, good hint. Also I inherit - in the real world code - from > 1 class, so I need this chaining. However, i appreciated your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for undefined

```
if (typeof this.member1 == "undefined") {
    //undefined
}
```

Comment: This does not work, because if the value remains sometimes undefined (no value assigned ) in Super it fails.

Comment: For the record, I don't think you should be leaving values unassigned, but set them to `null`. However, if you need to do that, @Darhazer's answer should work.