# Extend 'Component'; Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to extend React Component for that thing I dislike doing over and over again, the `this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);` requirement. So far I have tried:

MyComponent.js-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


// function bindReactMethod(this_value, method_name) {
//     // Bind all of your custom methods, like:
//     //   this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
//     this_value[method_name] = this_value[method_name].bind(this_value)
// }


// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192722/javascript-extending-class
class MyComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.bindReactMethods = this.bindReactMethods.bind(this)
    }

    bindReactMethods(this_value, method_name) {
        // Bind all of your custom methods, like:
        //   this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
        this_value[method_name] = this_value[method_name].bind(this_value)
    }
}
```

SearchBar.js-

```
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from '../utils/MyComponent';


export default class SearchBar extends MyComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {term: ''};
        this.bindReactMethods(['onInputChange'])
    }

    onInputChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.setState({term: event.target.value})
    }
```

fails with

```
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object
```

and

MyComponent.js-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


function bindReactMethod(this_value, method_name) {
    // Bind all of your custom methods, like:
    //   this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this_value[method_name] = this_value[method_name].bind(this_value)
}


// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192722/javascript-extending-class
class MyComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props, custom_methods=[]) {
        super(props);
        try {
            custom_methods.map((method_name) => {
                bindReactMethod(this, method_name)
            });
        }
        catch (error) { } // ignore error because that means the user didnt have custom methods to bind
    }
}
```

SearchBar.js-

```
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from '../utils/MyComponent';


export default class SearchBar extends MyComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props, ['onInputChange']);
        this.state = {term: ''};
    }

    onInputChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.setState({term: event.target.value})
    }
```

also fails on

```
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object
```

I would like to extend `Component` and always use my component, with this `bindReactMethods` callback being optional.

Comment: Are you exporting `MyComponent` from the module?

Comment: no I wasn't, now I get new error

Comment: What would it be?

Comment: In my defence, I claim python developer as excuse

Comment: If you're not exporting the class, you should be getting an exception when the module is loaded, not when the class is constructed. However a module transpiler might not consider this.

Comment: surprisingly nothing told me about the export issue

Comment: you can take an answer Andrew as it's working now, just post that I should export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ReactJS you should be using Composition instead of Inheritance.

> React has a powerful composition model, and we recommend using composition instead of inheritance to reuse code between components. [Link to docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

Comment: can you show example with my component please

Comment: @codyc4321 `<SearchBar>` should render a `<MyComponent>` instead of inheriting it; that's composition

Comment: While this is true, I have no idea how this answers the question?

Comment: ok, but will that help with saving me the annoyance of the `this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);`? If so I'll try it

Comment: I see the link I'm reading now

Comment: I read it. I think my problem is solved by the subclassing, now I can register custom components to bind this as a list instead of by hand

Answer (score 3):

`MyComponent` just wasn't being exported, the code works as:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


function bindReactMethod(this_value, method_name) {
    // Bind all of your custom methods, like:
    //   this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this_value[method_name] = this_value[method_name].bind(this_value)
}


// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192722/javascript-extending-class
export default class MyComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props, custom_methods=[]) {
        super(props);
        try {
            custom_methods.map((method_name) => {
                bindReactMethod(this, method_name)
            });
        }
        catch (error) { } // ignore error because that means the user didnt have custom methods to bind
    }
}
```

and

```
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from '../utils/MyComponent';


export default class SearchBar extends MyComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props, ['onInputChange']);
        this.state = {term: ''};
    }

    onInputChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.setState({term: event.target.value})
    }
```

also it allows regular super, like

```
constructor(props) {
            super(props);
```