# Can I use an object as a template for other objects?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to reduce the amount of duplicate code i'm writing in JS objects. I have a methods that I want to use where almost nothing is changing except the target and I'd like to extract that out and somehow get the target through the objects property name. Hopefully the example I put together makes sense.

```
myObject = {
  d: {
    get: function(list, id) {
      // do stuff
    },
    prop1: {
      data: [],
      list: myObject.config.lists.prop1.guid,
      get: function(a,b) {
        myObject.d.get(a,b)
      }
    },

    // I want to write this once and use the object key ("prop2") as an argument
    prop2: {
      data: [],
      list: myObject.config.lists.prop2.guid,
      get: function(a,b) {
        myObject.d.get(a,b)
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Tried something like this but getting error "Cannot read prop 'spec' of undefined:"

```
myObject = {
  d: {
    get: function(list, id) {
      // do stuff
    }
  },

  // Use this to duplicate shared funtions for similar
  spec: function(target) {
    return {
      data: [],
      list: myObject.config.lists[target].guid,

      get: function() {
        myObject.d.get(a, b);
      },
      update: "",
      delete: ""
    };
  },

  // some how return `myObject.spec.get()`, allowing me to use myObject.d.prop1.get()
  prop1: myObject.spec.apply(this, "prop1"),
  prop2: myObject.spec.apply(this, "prop2")
};
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a minimal complete example. You reference things not defined in the example provided, which itself is missing a closing brace and rather lengthy. You also are using a keyword (get) as an object property. While that's legal in JavaScript, I'd think twice about doing so.

Comment: @JaredSmith cleaned it up, hopefully that helps

Comment: If you are calling `.get()` on the object, just use `this.data` and `this.list`…

Comment: Why not just explicitly pass the `target` property name as a parameter to  `spec()`?

Comment: Agree with @Bergi, while I think this whole idea seems a little convoluted, that's the most logical way with minimal changes to your existing structure.

Comment: @JaredSmith interested in hearing if there's a better way if this seems too complex / convoluted. The reason I'm trying this approach is there's going to be a lot more methods like `get, update, delete, etc etc` so I'm trying to find a way to write it once.

Comment: @Bergi yea passing the target like this `prop1: myObject.spec("prop1")` would be fine actually. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that tho. I'm getting an error `cannot read spec of undefined` when I try it in the console.

Comment: @Batman sounds like what you want is a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). You can then trap calls to the normal operations rather than using keywords as methods. If compatibility is an issue your stuck doing it the long way.

Comment: @Batman Yeah, you [cannot put that `spec` function inside the same object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572)

Comment: Well, i dont know how it works in javascript, but in PHP you can extend another class. The child class will have all methods and property's from it's parent which then can be overwritten (`class MyObject extends BaseObject {}`). Maybe you can google on something simular? Just an idea.

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192722/javascript-extending-class

Answer (score 0):

So far the only way I was able to get it working was by setting `prop1` and `prop2` outside of the initial deceleration like this and explicitly declaring the `target` like @Bergi suggested:

```
var myObject = myObject || {};
myObject = {
  d: {
    get: function(list, id) {
      // do stuff
    }
  },

  // Use this to duplicate shared funtions for similar
  spec: function(target) {
    return {
      data: [],
      list: target,

      get: function() {
        myObject.d.get(a, b);
      },
      update: "",
      delete: ""
    };
  }

};

// some how return `myObject.spec.get()`, allowing me to use myObject.d.prop1.get()
myObject.prop1 = myObject.spec("prop1");
myObject.prop2 = myObject.spec("prop2");
```