# Inheriting Errors

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, error-handling

What is the purpose of inheriting from the `Error` class?

An example of inheriting from the `Error` class is shown.

```js
class InputError extends Error {}

function promptDirection(question) {
  let result = prompt(question);
  if (result.toLowerCase() == "left") return "L";
  if (result.toLowerCase() == "right") return "R";
  throw new InputError("Invalid direction: " + result);
}
for (;;) {
  try {
    let dir = promptDirection("Where?");
    console.log("You chose ", dir);
    break;
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof InputError) {
      console.log("Not a valid direction. Try again.");
    } else {
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

My question is:

What is the purpose of making a new class of `InputError`? Can't we just use `Error` instead of `InputError`?

Comment: Try clicking cancel and you will see why

Comment: You can just use Error. Please see why you extend class here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15192747/2822041

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial That shows *how* to extend a class (which the OP already knows), it does not explain *why* to extend it

Comment: the link already show examples of what extending classes does.  In this instance, InputError is unnecessary.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Uh, `InputError` has a clear purpose, what makes you think it was unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

If you had not extended `Error` to create a separate `InputError` class and just thrown a normal `Error`, then `if (e instanceof InputError)` would not work.

Of course there are other ways to distinguish errors (such as matching against the error `.message`, or - safer - on a custom `.code` property), but building an error hierarchy using subclasses and using `instanceof` is common and reflects the design used in many other programming languages.