# how to pass init parameter to base class in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2107571/494461

```
function Base (string ) {
  this.color = string;
}

function Sub (string) {

}
Sub.prototype = new Base( );


var instance = new Sub ('blue' );
```

How do I pass the string variable ahead to the base class?

Comment: Maybe the following answer can help you with this as well.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just invoke the `Base` function, like this

```
function Base (string) {
    this.color = string;
}

function Sub (string) {
    Base.call(this, string);
}
```

Using the `Function.prototype.call`, you are setting the current object to the `Base` function call as the current object in `Sub`. So, `Base` will be actually creating the `color` property in `Sub` object only.

Also, the prototype of an Object should depend only on the prototype of other objects, not on others objects. So, you would want to inherit with the common way

```
Sub.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
```

Comment: where should I put the line ------- Sub.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype); --------In above context?

Comment: @user494461 Instead of `Sub.prototype = new Base( );`