# How to have multiple objects extend 1 object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

In javascript, I have a object (like an abstract class) defined like

```
var abstractclass = function() {

};
```

Now I want to have some other classes extend `abstractclass`. This is how I do it, but I don't think it's the best way. I just create an instance of the parent in the class, and then I just use the parent.

```
var abstractclassA = function() {
    var parent = new abstractclass();
};

var abstractclassB = function() {
    var parent = new abstractclass();
};

var abstractclassC = function() {
    var parent = new abstractclass();
};

var instance1 = new abstractclassA();
var instance2 = new abstractclassB();
var instance3 = new abstractclassC();
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to inherit from a class in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107556/how-to-inherit-from-a-class-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you really mean "abstract" in the OOP sense?

Comment: No, I just called it abstract.

Comment: What are you doing with these `parent` variables? Nothing? Then what's that `abstractclass` thing all about? Please provide your whole, meaningful code.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to use a library like [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) they have an extend function, I think it will do what you want.
If not, then you can take a look at it's [Annotated Source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) and see how they implemented it.
Lastly, [backbone's objects](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend) do something very similar to what you seek. So you can also take a look at their [Annotated Source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#helpers)

Answer (score -1):

Usually I do this:

```
var abstractClass = function(){

};

var classB = function(){

};

classB.prototype = new abstractClass();
```

this way, the instance of classB will result as instance of abstractClass too

Comment: I would use Object.create instead (if you can cut support off at IE9). so
classB.prototype = Object.create(abstractClass.prototype); or just pass in an object literal.