# Inheritence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I get a strange bug when I implement inheritence in Javascript using prototypes. I am wondering if someone can explain this. In the following code,
I am trying to derive a child class from a parent class:

```
            parent_class=function(byref)
            {   
                if( !parent_class.prototype._vtbl )
                {
                        parent_class.prototype.parent_func= function(o) { return alert("parent_func"); }
                        parent_class.prototype._vtbl = true;
                }
            }



            child=function(byref)
            {
                parent_class.call(this,byref);

                if( !child.prototype._vtbl )
                {
                        child.prototype = new parent_class;
                        child.prototype.child_func      = parent_class.prototype.parent_func;

                        child.prototype._vtbl = true;
                }

            }


            function dotest()
            {
                var pub = new child;
                alert( pub.child_func );

                var pub2    = new child;
                alert( pub2.child_func );
            }

            dotest();
```

When you run the test in a browser (Firefox or IE), you get two alerts. The first one says that pub.child_func is undefined, the second one says that the pub.child_func is a valid function and is parent_class.parent_func. Why do you see this behavior. Is this a bug?

Comment: It's a bug in your code. Never initialise prototypes from within the constructor function!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568239/javascriptinstanceof-operator and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255957/assigning-prototype-methods-inside-the-constructor-function-why-not

Answer (score 1):

Order of execution in javascript of such construct:

```
function SomeClass () { body(); }
var x = new SomeClass();
```

is this:

1. new object which inherits from `SomeClass.prototype` is created (the prototype for the object is chosen here, before code of the constructor is executed)
2. `body();` gets executed
3. created object is assigned to x

What you can do in your example is use [`.__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), although you really really should not:

```
child = function (byref) {
    parent_class.call(this, byref);
    if (!child.prototype._vtbl) {
        child.prototype = new parent_class;
        child.prototype.child_func = parent_class.prototype.parent_func;
        child.prototype._vtbl = true;
    }
    this.__proto__ = child.prototype;
}
```

What you really should do is this:

```
child = function (byref) {
    parent_class.call(this, byref);
}
child.prototype = Object.create(parent_class.prototype);
child.prototype.child_func = parent_class.prototype.parent_func;
child.prototype._vtbl = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do JavaScript inheritance might be the factory pattern:

```
function Animal(name) {
    return {
        run: function() {
          alert(name + " is running!")
        }
    }
}

var animal = Animal("fox");
animal.run();

function Rabbit(name) {
  var rabbit = Animal(name);

  rabbit.bounce = function() {
    this.run();
    console.log(name + " bounces");
  }

  return rabbit;
}

var rabbit = Rabbit("rabbit");
rabbit.bounce();
```

Source: http://javascript.info/tutorial/factory-constructor-pattern

Comment: If you want to use the factory pattern so that you can call your functions without `new` (as in `rabbit = Animal(name);`), then you must not use `this`.

Comment: You're right, serious copy and paste error...fixed, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: No, it's not browser mistake, it's expected behavior.

**Detailed answer**:
When a constructor function is called with `new`, reference to it's `prototype` is copied into objects's `__proto__`. Later on this property is used for prototypal lookups for this object. 
Your code is really weird from point of view of javascript developer, when you modify `prototype` of constructor during constructor call execution. However, it works. Because, after `var parent = new parent_class();` the following  is true `parent.__proto__ === parent_class.prototype`. It is the SAME reference. Thus adding properties to `parent_class.prototype` is automatically relfected in `parent` object via prototypal lookup.
Unfortunately I can't post comments yet, so I have to reference from my answer, @RyszardFiński it is not a correct statement that `prototype` is defined before contructor called and can't be changed afterwards. It is the same object and unless you change the reference changes will be reflected immediately for all instantiated objects

However in `child` code in OP ruins references when `child.prototype` is assigned to a new object.

> `child.prototype = new parent_class;`

`child.prototype` start pointing a to new instance of `parent_class` (#1). Instance references look like below

```
pub.__proto__ === child.prototype
pub2.__proto__ === parentInstance1
child.prototype === parentInstance2
```

If you remove the line of code where `child.prototype` is assigned everything will start working as you expect it

```
pub.__proto__ === child.prototype
pub2.__proto__ === child.prototype
child.prototype === child.prototype
child.prototype has properties _vtbl and child_func
```

Comment: Your suggestion works. And I understand why now. But does this mean that mean that this is an acceptable alternative? The discussion pointed by Bergi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255957/assigning-prototype-methods-inside-the-constructor-function-why-not  does not seem to be conclusive.  The real objective is to find an approach where the function table is not recreated every time, but just once. What is the best approach to achieve that?

Comment: While my post is an exact answer to your original exact question (the way it was formulated), I don't think this is a good appraoch for inheritance. A single function table can't be achieved for functions that use private variables, however you can copy them to the new object's prototype. Because inheritance in JS is prototypal not classic. If you really want to go a bit academic in this, i suggest you read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30996891/4573999) in detail